# .htaccess rewrite all, except one page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to solve a problem with my .htaccess file.

I would like to use 301 redirect from my "old" doman to the "new" one, except some certain pages. Like "PageA" and "PageB".

The code thats working and iam using for redirect all is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

"PageA", and "PageB" has to be redirected to the "new" domain too, but to a certain address. Like:

```
old.com/pageA  ---> new.com/something/pageA
old.com/pageB  ---> new.com/something2/pageB
```

What code should i add to .htaccess, to add some exceptions with certain addresses ?

Comment: Side note: it should be `^www\.old\.com$`, not `^www.old.com`...

Comment: You have to define "exception rewriting rules" for specific targets, add those _before_ the general catch all rule you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(pageA|pageB)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new.com/test/%1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: doesnt working :(
Everything is redirecting like to second code. No exceptions.

Comment: Everything is redirecting like the second code. No exceptions.

Comment: Made sure I have correctly typed everything, but no luck :(.